# When you submit a bank statement to a consulate for a visa application, do they scrutinize your list of purchases?

Tags: visas, usa, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm about to apply for a US tourist visa and one of the recommended documents is a bank statement for the past 3 months. My balance movements [should be satisfactory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and my purchase history is quite mundane. But, for the sake of the question, let's say I've been paying extensively by card in establishments of ill repute.

Would the US consulate check out each transaction on my statement? Or would they simply have a look at the closing balance and ignore the rest?

Comment: I doubt they are really interested in what you spend on such things, but I would try to make sure that your statement does not show payments to certain organisations that the country you want to go to doesn't like - but then I'm more thinking about terrorist organisations or unfriendly governments and the like.

Comment: @oerkelens I'm thinking more of things like strip clubs. Or perhaps you waste 50% of your earnings on bars.

Comment: And most of the other 50% on liver transplants.

Comment: Who knows? For many visa applications they don't even check the bank account whatsoever.

Comment: If you submit it, they can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the banks I know let you request a statement of assets, as described here for the swiss bank UBS: [Statement of Assets](https://www.ubs.com/microsites/hilfe/en/account/order-statement-of-assets.html). I don't know if it is enough for them, but you could give it a try by sending them only this statement. If it is not detailed enough, they will ask for the full bank statement.